# Applying the chain rule on vectors and matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors, real-numbers, chain-rule

I need to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the following

y = $||A^Tx - b||_2^2$ where $A \in R^{3x3}, b \in R^{3x1}, x \in R^{3x1}, y \in R,$ and $||.||_2$  is the euclidean norm so for example $||z||_2^2 = z^Tz$ for $z \in R^{3x1}$. I'm familiar with the chain rule but I've never really used it in this way. Also, I'm not sure what $R^{3x3}$ represents and how I can use it with the chain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the vector
$$z=A^Tx-b$$
Write the function in terms of this new vector. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 y &= z^Tz \cr
dy &= 2z^Tdz = 2z^T(A^Tdx) = (2Az)^Tdx \cr
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} &= 2Az = 2A(A^Tx-b) \cr\cr
}$$
The symbol ${\mathbb R}^{m\times n}$ denotes a matrix of real numbers with $m$ rows and $n$ columns.